# How we can add php code to model file in CAKE PHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Subscriber' => array(
        'className' => 'Subscriber',
        'foreignKey' => 'UserID',
        'conditions' => array(
             'Subscriber.end_date >=' => date('Y-m-d')
        ), 
));
```

Here `date('Y-m-d')` gives html parse error. Even echo and print is not working in model file.

My aim is to get data from all subscribed users table till current date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
public $hasOne = array(
'Subscriber' => array(
  'className' => 'Subscriber',
  'foreignKey' => 'UserID',
  'conditions' => array(
    'Subscriber.end_date >= date("Y-m-d")'
  ),
));
```

It will work as per your requirement